# Reverse Word Pyramid

Tags: wordplay, pattern, connect-wall

Group these words into groups of:

- Six
- Five
- Four
- Three
- Two
- and One.

Then, figure out why this is a 'reverse' pyramid.

[image]

Comment: Just to check - WORLD appears twice... This is correct, yes? Thanks.

Comment: that is not a mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The groups are:

> Six things associated with "1"...
>  "HYDROGEN (Element # 1)", "(First) WORLD", "(First place) WINNER", "ACE (value 1)", "MERCURY (1st planet from the sun)", "GOLD (1st place)"
>  Five things associated with "2"...
>  "SILVER (2nd place)", "MINUTE (football two-minute warning, or a unit of time similar to second... neither is quite compelling, but we know this goes here by process of elimination)", "COIN (2 sides)", "(The Two) TOWERS", "BETA (Second)"
>  Four things associated with "3"...
>  "(The three) BEARS", "(Third) WORLD (countries)", "EARTH (3rd planet from the sun)", "MARCH (3rd month)
>  Three things associated with "4"...
>  "(Four) SEASONS", "SQUARE (4 sides)", "COMPASS (4 cardinal directions)
>  Two things associated with "5"...
>  "HIGH (five)", "MAY (5th month)"
>  One thing associated with "6"...
>  "CARBON (Element #6)

This is a 'reverse' pyramid

> Because the # of items in each group is exactly reverse of the number the group represents!  That is, instead of one 1, two 2's, three 3's as might be expected, the counts are reversed to six 1's, five 2's, etc.

Comment: Nice job. Only thing is one of your justifications is not my intended justification, that would be ROT13(ZVAHGR naq frpbaq ner obgu havgf bs gvzr, urapr 'gjb')

Comment: I had wondered if that was what was intended. I added it in.

Comment: This is a very interesting puzzle! I'm glad someone solved it!